# 3 queries using the same set of IDs in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have 3 queries:

```
select * from customers
where account_id in (select id from accounts where nrb in ('123', '234', '345', '456'));

select * from cards
where account_id in (select id from accounts where nrb in ('123', '234', '345', '456'));

select * from users
where account_id in (select id from accounts where nrb in ('123', '234', '345', '456'));
```

All of them use the same subquery to get the accounts' ids based on nrb. What is the best way to replace 3 same subqueries. I want it to look smooth and clear.

We're talking OracleDB case.

Comment: How do you want to run this? SQL script (in client such as SQL Developer)?

Comment: Also, what do you want to do with the result sets afterwards? It's seems unlikely you want to run three independent queries with a common filter and then **not** want to combine the results somehow afterwards.

Comment: Your only solution if you want to share data among three queries without using PL/SQL is to use (temporary) tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff and why not a good old WITH (query subfactoring)? Seems obvious to me and it seems also impossible to me that you haven't thought about it. So explain why I am wrong :)

Comment: @ThomasG . . . How are you going to return three result sets with different columns using `with`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff ah. Yeah I see why I am wrong. For some reason my eyes saw UNIONs between the queries :D I thought it was one query and not 3. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If no_columns & it's type same then you can do :

```
with cte as (
     select col1, col2, col3, . . .
     from customers c union all
     . . . 
     select col1, col2, col3, . . .
     from users u
)
select c.*
from cte c
where exists (select 1 
              from accounts a 
              where a.id = c.account_id and a.nrb in (123, 234, 345, 456)
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just left join them.. and use an alias to columns you need..

something like

```
select id, 
customers.id as customers_id,
cards.id as cards_id,
users.id as users_id,
customers.*, cards.*, users.*
from accounts 
left outer join customers
on customers.account_id = accounts.id
left outer join cards
on cards.account_id = accounts.id
left outer join users
on users.account_id = accounts.id
where nrb in ('123', '234', '345', '456'))
and (customers.id is not null or cards.id is not null or users.id is not null);
```